# stopping an embedded sound in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

My sound is embedded in as Assets class

```
[Embed(source="../../assets/gameloop.mp3")]
        private static var gameLoopSound:Class;
        public static var gameLoop:Sound;
```

The sound is played in another class

```
Assets.gameLoop.play()
```

but how do I stop this sound?  It seems to me that a .stop() method would be the obvious way but this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this approach, you lose the link to `SoundChannel` object that you can use to stop the sound that's being played. You do two things: First, make a publicly available variable of type `SoundChannel` and assign it the result value of `Assets.gameLoop.play()` call. Second, put a `yourVariable.stop()` where you need that music to stop. Most likely you will use another variable in `Assets` class. But, for better security, make a pair of static functions that will address this pair of variables, like this:

```
private static var gameLoopChannel:SoundChannel;
private static var gameLoop:Sound=new gameLoopSound(); 

public static function playGameLoop():void {
    if (gameLoopChannel) return;
    gameLoopChannel=gameLoop.play();
}
public static function stopGameLoop():void {
    if (!gameLoopChannel) return; // no sound is being played
    gameLoopChannel.stop();
    gameLoopChannel=null;
}
```